# what is the modulation scheme of IEEE 802.11 beacon frame?

Tags: wifi

What is the modulation scheme of  IEEE 802.11 beacon frame, is it fixed to BPSK? 
Since a station knows the modulation scheme that is supported by the AP via beacon frame, I think beacon frame must use a fixed modulation scheme otherwise the station does not know how to demodulation the signal.

Answer (score 3):

Kind of. The AP must transmit beacons frames that can be "understood" by all stations desiring to associate it with it. In other words, the AP must use beacons that can be understood by the lowest common denominator. For example, a 802.11b and 802.11b/g has to beacon at 1mbps with CCK where as a 802.11g (g-only) can beacon at 6mbps using OFDM, etc, etc.